# Slowness on the first load of Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-farm

I have installed new SharePoint 2013 Farm on a single server (**windows server 2012 R2**) (VM, **8 processors**, **12GB RAM**)

I created one Web application defined it in DNS and it's working fine.
A part of the fact that it's Very slow on the first load of the page.

It takes up to a minute. After when we switch between sub sites it's go very fast.

Do you have any Idea how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, since Sharepoint is an IIS hosted .NET application. On the first request all the Application Pools have to be started, dependencies get loaded, etc.

Additionally the AppPool-Recycling will tear down everything after some time of inactivity (normally after 30 min.).

There are several "Warm-Up" scripts around. You could try this one: https://github.com/spjeff/spbestwarmup

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you it's clear, Now I know what to search. I Used this powershell but it make some conflict with google chrome. However i knwo what is the cose thank you